# Using two permalink structures for 2 types of posts

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, permalinks

I'm new to wordpress and currently facing an issue on permalinks.

For example I have a page for privacy policy and the permalink for that page is like this

```
 https://testsitename.io/privacy
```

Above page works with the this permalink structure in permalink settings

```
https://testsitename.io/archives/123
```

I also integrated a react app to wordpress and, the react app produces a permalink like

```
https://testsitename.io/crazy_droid
```

Above page loads with a custom permalink structure of `https://testsitename.io/%post_id%`

The issue is when i select a permalink structure i can only get one type of page to load. Other page will give a 404 not found error. How can i fix this issue .
NOTE: i'm a newbie to wordpress

UPDATE:

For the react app, url is created through a `register_post_type` as follows

```
function custom_post_type()
    {
        register_post_type(
            'expert',[
            'public' => true, 
            'label' => 'Experts',
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '/' ),
            'supports' => array( 'title','editor','thumbnail' )
            ]);
    }
```

Comment: When you change your permalinks structure, do you also remember to flush your rules, else the database won't know what to do with it. - basically "regenerate permalinks" after you have changed the structure.

Comment: I bought the "permalinks manager pro" plugin a loooong time ago, and it is on basically all of my sites. In there, you can set any structure you want, for any post type and have it create a flush and automatic redirects, brilliant if you have a bunch of post types that you want with different structures. Best dollars I have ever spend. - that said - it can also be done in the registration of the post types code if you want to code it yourself.

Comment: @Stender i have updated my question with the function that creates the permalink for my react app. Could you please point me in the right direction. I'm very new to wordpress

Comment: kinda dangerous thing you are going into - By not having a slug for your CPT, conflicts can happen easily if the slug for your custom post type is the same as a page or post's slug, also, I guess you need the following in your registration `'with_front' => false`, and then regenerate your permalinks - but wordpress only expects pages and posts to have this structure, so there might be more code needed with a `pre_get_posts` action, so you can have "experts" in the same logic.

Comment: Found some links for you - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291735/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type-results-in-404/292379#292379, and https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/204210/82677 both solves the issue, but the best would be to make a mix of those two answers.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/282040/82677